# Meteor "load more" button with Iron Router & no "Posts Limit" in the url

Tags: javascript, meteor, real-time, reload, iron-router

So I'm building a multi-page Meteor app with the Iron-Router. On one page (not the home page) I have a list of items being displayed from a collection, where the Iron-Router "waits on" data from the collection with a limit that depends on a Session variable.

When the load more button is pressed, the Session variable changes, and the page reloads with more items.

ALL I want to do is reload the page at the position of the old load more button (the new one is placed at the end of the new list), or somehow make this transition cleaner. See http://microscope.meteor.com/ for a perfect example.

The HTML:

```
 <template name="postsList">
    {{#each postsWithRank}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}

  {{#if moreResults}}
    {{> loadMore}}
  {{/if}}
 </template>


<template name="loadMore">
 <a class="load-more">Load more</a>
</template>
```

The helpers:

```
Template.postsList.helpers({ 
 postsWithRank: function() {
   Posts.find({category: this.title}).rewind();
   return Posts.find({category: this.title}).map(function(post, index, cursor) {
     post._rank = index;
     return post;
   });
 },
 moreResults: function() {
  return parseInt(Session.get('limit')) == Posts.find().fetch().length;
 }
});


Template.loadMore.events({
"click": function(event) {  
event.preventDefault();
 Session.set("limit", Session.get("limit") + 10);
 }   
})
```

The Router:

```
  listingPageController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'listingPage',
  sort: {submitted: -1, _id: -1},
 limit: function() {return Session.get('limit')},
 findOptions: function() {
  return {sort: this.sort, title: this.params.title, limit: this.limit()}; 
 },
  waitOn: function() {
  return Meteor.subscribe("posts", this.findOptions());
  },
 data: function() {
  return Listings.findOne({title: this.params.title})
 }
});
```

Thanks!

So I have no router code for the postsList template. The postsList template is being rendered inside of the listingPage template, like so:

```
<template name="listingPage">

  <!--main-->
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

    {{>leftBarListingPage}}

    <!--right-->
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <h2 id="sec1"> 
    <div class="listingPageHeader">
     <div style= "text-transform:capitalize"> Posts in</div> 
     <div class="smallListings">&nbsp;</div>
     {{title}} </div> 
   </h2>


  <p>
     <div class="posts">
     {{> postsList}}
    </div>
  </p>


</div><!--/right-->
```

The {{title}} attribute comes from the listingPageController, which works with two Collections -> a Listings collection (for static parent categories) and a Posts collection (for the posts within those categories)

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem? You've only said what you want to do not any errors/problems you are getting.

If the page is moving back to the top it's because of a bug with the latest version of iron router, edit your smart.json and change/insert the line

```
"iron-router": {
  "version": "0.7.0"
}
```

Then test and see if it works,  also you may want to run Session.setDefault("limit", 10) in a before action as you will not always have that session otherwise.

Comment: That's a good catch with the iron-router. However, I don't think it worked for me. I suppose my problem is that the entire page is re-rendering, as opposed to just loading more posts at the bottom, which brings the focus of the page to the top. Can you help with this?

Comment: Maybe try upgrading to the latest iron router 0.8.0

Comment: still nothing. What exactly was the bug with iron-router? Could it be something else?

Comment: not sure, can you post your router code for the postsList template?